# Construction of descending sequence of subset of infinite set

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $X$ be an infinite set.
Is it possible to construct a sequencing $X=X_0\supset X_1\supset X_2\supset\cdots$ that satisfies the following?

- For each $i\geq0$, $\operatorname{card}(X_n)=\operatorname{card}(X)$.($\operatorname{card}(X)$ means the cardinality of $X$.)
- $\bigcap_{i\geq0} X_i=\emptyset$.

This problem can be found in the proof of Theorem 3.1 in [Cha60].

[Cha60] S. U. Chase (1960) "Direct products of module",
*Trans. Amer. Math. Soc.*, Vol. 97, No. 3, pp. 457-473,
DOI:10.2307/1993382.

Comment: The intersection of the first zero to $n$ is $X_n$. If the intersection of all of them is empty, what does that mean of the limit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fix an infinite set $X$. Write $X=\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb N} Y_n$, where $|Y_n|=|X|$ for all $n$ and $n\neq m\to Y_n\cap Y_m=\emptyset$.

Put $Z_n:=\bigcup_{i<n} Y_i$. Note that $n<m\to Z_n\subset Z_m$, $Z_0=\emptyset$, and $\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb{N}} Z_n=X$.

Let $X_n:=X\setminus Z_n$. Note that $Y_{n+1}\subset X_n$, so that $|X|=|Y_{n+1}|\le |X_n|\le |X|$. Therefore, $|X_n|=|X|$ for all $n\in\mathbb N$. Moreover, $X_0=X$ and $X_{n+1}\subset X_n$.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't express myself well.
I'm looking for a construction that works for any infinite set $X$.

Comment: @winter_mute Ah yes sorry, that's a much more sensible question. No need to apologize, my reading of your question made very little sense (it was very late at night). Please see my edit.